# How to make generation of wordlist faster?

Tags: python, generator, word-list

Soooo for example I want to generate all possibilities from 0 to 1 with 30 decimals. But the process takes too long. I have made this code for it to generate the numbers and store them in a file

```
counter = 1
wordlist_num = open("Output.txt", "w")

while counter < 10 ** 30:
    f = float(f'0.{counter:030}')
    wordlist_num.write("%.30f" % f + "\n")
    print("%.30f" % f)
    counter += 1
```

Is there a way that I can generate all the possibilities over night? If not is there a way that maybe I can speed up the process and make it more efficient?

Comment: see if its faster if you don't print it. Printing can be slow

Comment: `counter` is used before it is defined here.

Comment: You could split it intro threads to run concurrently.

Comment: It is slow because you are writting to a file, you are `print`ing, you are converting a `string` to a `float` and you are doing a lot of `string` concatenasions . Basically everything you are doing here is an expensive operation.

Comment: oukej you have any idea for a better, more optimized algorithm?

Comment: How big and fast is your disk ?  This will generate a file of at least 29,103,830,456,733,703,613 terabytes which would take 410,880,627,629,090 years to write on a very fast SSD at 2.3GB/s